# Debugging groovy code in groovysh step by step

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovysh

I'm new to Java and Groovy, and this is a really simple question on debugging groovy code in `groovysh` step by step.

```
$ groovysh
groovy:000> String str = "abcd"
===> abcd
groovy:000> println str
Unknown property: str
```

In interactives debug shell for all other languages, I was able to define a variable and use it in *all the following steps*. How to do that as well in `groovysh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined in the `groovysh` [documentation page](https://groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html#GroovyShell-Variables), by default all variables are untyped and thus using `def` or specific type identifier (like `String`) does not work. In this case, the proper syntax is just `str = "abcd"`.

```
$ groovysh
Groovy Shell (3.0.6, JVM: 11.0.6)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> str = "abcd"
===> abcd
groovy:000> str
===> abcd
groovy:000> :S variables
Variables:
  str = abcd
  _ = abcd
===> [str:abcd, _:abcd]
```

As you can see in the example above, you can list all variables that are registered in the shell session with the `:S variables` command. (You can list all available commands with `:h` executed in the shell window.)

However, there is a way to turn on typed variables. This is called the interpreted mode and it can be activated with `:= interpretedMode` command like in the example below:

```
$ groovysh
Groovy Shell (3.0.6, JVM: 11.0.6)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> str = "abcd"
===> abcd
groovy:000> str
===> abcd
groovy:000> :S variables
Variables:
  str = abcd
  _ = abcd
===> [str:abcd, _:abcd]
groovy:000> := interpreterMode
groovy:000> String str2 = "efgh"
===> efgh
groovy:000> str2
===> efgh
groovy:000> str == str2
===> false
groovy:000> :S variables
Variables:
  str = abcd
  _ = false
  groovysh_collected_boundvars = [str2:efgh]
  str2 = efgh
===> [str:abcd, _:false, groovysh_collected_boundvars:[str2:efgh], str2:efgh]
```